# Change the Title on a Java Swing App

Tags: java, swing, title, menubar

How would I go about changing the Title (in the menu bar) of my java app. When it is launched, at least in mac (My primary development environment), it displays the full class name instead of the title. I am using Swing as my GUI maker, and the `this.setTitle("JeopardMe");` only makes the Title Bar change. I want to change the display in the menu bar.

*I would have posted screenshots here, but apparently needing 10 reputation to post images and having 10 reputation is not allowed*

I think I need to change the way the system looks at the program overall, because in the force quit window, (A Mac's rough equivalent to Task Manager), is Displays the class name, and I'm not sure that changing the menu bar would also change the force quit text. Any way to change the program's overall identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the application from the command line add the following argument:

```
-Xdock:name=AppName
```

where AppName is the title you want to see.

Comment: Will that stay even when I send it to a different computer?

Comment: That will need to be added to the command line every time you run the application.  You're better of the Windows users.  Not even a command line option for them.

Comment: So how would I create a permanent rename of my application, because I'm planning on distributing it cross-platform, (either as a raw-jar file or somewhat packaged, i havent figured that out yet). I looked into jarbundler, and there seems to be a title section i can fill out, would that work?

Comment: A custom launcher.  In windows land there's launch4j.  I'm not sure about macs, but jarbundler *sounds* like the same kind of thing.  Although if you just build a regular shortcut (or the mac equivalent), can't you specify command line parameters?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no experience developing for windows, and was planning on releasing a naked jar file, but would like something a little more...professional.

Comment: ok i looked into launch4j, which is the windows equivalent of jarbundler, which takes a jar file in one end a out comes a shiny new .app file on the other. I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: excellent.  I helped someone today.  :)  I kind of needed that.

Comment: well you sure did, have a nice day!